# Why not pipe list of file names into cat?

Tags: unix, pipe

What is the design rationale that `cat` doesn't take list of file names from pipe input? Why did the designers choose that the following does not work?

```
ls *.txt | cat
```

Instead of this, they chose that we need to pass the file names as argument to `cat` as:

```
ls *.txt | xargs cat
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you say `ls *.txt | cat` doesn't work, you should say that doesn't work as you expect. In fact, that works in the way it was thought to work.

From `man`:

```
cat - Concatenate FILE(s), or standard input, to standard output
```

Suppose the next output:

```
$ ls *.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

... the input to `cat` will be:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

...and that's exactly what `cat` output in the *standard output*

In some shells, it's equivalent to:

```
cat <(ls *.txt)
```

or

```
ls *.txt > tmpfile; cat tmpfile
```

So, `cat` is really working as their designers expected to do so.

---

On the other hand, what you are expecting is that `cat` interprets its input as a set of filenames to read and concatenate their content, but when you *pipe* to `cat`, that input works as a lonely file.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very simple and clear explanation. Especially, this line clarified the issue to me: `ls *.txt > tmpfile; cat tmpfile`

Comment: Is there any reason not to just simply `cat *.txt`?

Comment: Yes, because I wanted to show that `ls *.txt | cat` works the same as `cat <(ls *.txt)` in the sense that it is reading from the standard input.

Answer (score 4):

To make it short, `cat` is a command, like `echo` or `cp`, and few others, which cannot convert pipe redirected input stream into arguments.

So, xargs, is used, to pass the input stream as an argument to the command.

More details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs

As a former unix SA, and now, Python developer, I believe I could compare xargs, to StringIO/CStringIO, in Python, as it kind of helps the same way.

When it comes to your question: Why didn't they allow stream input? Here is what I think

Nobody but them could answer this.

I believe, however, than cat is meant to print to stdout the content of a file, while the command echo, was meant to print to stdout the content of a string.

Each of these commands, had a specific role, when created.

Comment: I believe that it can be answered considering the design principles of Unix because `cat` is a very common command. So every design decision in `cat` are most probably made deliberately.

Comment: Yes, exactly, see my edited answer. Unix has tons of principles, and each of the base shell commands have a specific role they have been created for.

Comment: Why do you say `cat` doesn't accept pipe redirection? In fact, it works fine as a filter.

Comment: Ooops, corrected, indeed. I meant it is a different usage. And doing a pipe to cat is like redirecting stdout to stdout and most of the time has no real interest.