# how to pipe ls into cat with xargs so that filenames are listed?

Tags: linux, pipe, cat, ls, xargs

For using `cat` to output `*.txt` files within a specific directory, how can I insert the filename as a "break" before each file?

```
file #1
contents of file

file #2
contents of file
```

*ideally as an easy to remember few `bash` commands.*

see also:

[Why not pipe list of file names into cat?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26443951/262852)

Comment: Please clarify the question, what do you mean by 'insert the filename as a 'break' ?

Comment: I just mean print the file name somehow, as `ls foo` would result in.  along those lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One more option to @0stone0 answer
You can use `tail` insted of cat:

```
tail -n +1 *
```

Output:

```
==> file-1.txt <==
contents of file


==> file-2.txt <==
contents of file
```

Comment: excellent.  can I use `cat` or `nl` rather than tail?  or, I suppose it's probably possible to just `tail` an entire file.

Comment: the `-n +1` will tail all the file content.

Answer (score 8):

Improved answer;

Instead of an separate `-exec basename`, using just `-print` will show the filename:

```
find . -type f -print -exec cat {} \;
```

---

You could use a [`find`](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) command with [multiple `-exec`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119946/find-exec-with-multiple-commands);

```sh
find . -type f -iname '*.txt' -exec basename {} \; -exec cat {} \;
```

```
-> ls
a.txt  b.txt

-> find . -type f -iname '*.txt' -exec basename {} \; -exec cat {} \;
b.txt
b
a.txt
a
```

Comment: `find` is quite useful for other reasons, getting familiar with the syntax could be quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to search a string in list of files then this should be best option. This will print the filenames as well

grep "some string" *.log