# How to grep output from tail and include file names?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe, tail

How is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65218197/262852):

```
tail -n +1 *.txt | grep foo
```

slightly modified to show the filename?

When it's not piped, the filename is conveniently part of the output.  Can the `grep` operation be confined to the content of the file, while preserving that the filename is output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a *simple* regex that matches;

- All the filename's; `==>(.*)<==`
- Your 'search' string (eg: `foo`)

```sh
tail -n +1 * | grep -E '==>(.*)<==|foo'
```

---

Anther option, based on [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65218023/5625547) by running the `-exec` through `grep` like so:

```
find . -type f -print -exec grep 'foo'  {} \;
```

---

Example using **both methods** in 3 files (`{a,b,c}.txt`) all containing `a`, `b`, and `c`.

```
bash-3.2$ tail -n +1 *
==> a.txt <==
a
b
c


==> b.txt <==
a
b
c


==> c.txt <==
a
b
c


bash-3.2$ tail -n +1 * | grep -E '==>(.*)<==|c'
==> a.txt <==
c
==> b.txt <==
c
==> c.txt <==
c


bash-3.2$ find . -type f -print -exec grep 'c' {} \;
./c.txt
c
./b.txt
c
./a.txt
c
```